# JSTL: Does c:forEach guarantee List ordering in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

My JSP contains the following snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${rulesForm.rules}" var="rule" varStatus="counter">
        <tr id="rules${counter.index}" name="rules[${counter.index}]">
```

"rules" itself is a `List<Rule>`.

When I pass my `ModelAndView` object back from my Spring MVC Controller, I can see that my List is in the correct order.

However, when it is then rendered on screen, the ordering is somewhat random. I also have JavaScript that performs some modifications on the DOM, but I don't see this doing any reordering.
Therefore, I am wondering if `c:forEach` is the culprit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet [`<c:forEach/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) uses an `Iterator` in most implementations, therefore it relies on underlying collection order. Thus if you pass `List`, the order *will* be preserved, which is not true for `Set`s.

Although the documentation does not state that:

> items [...] Collection of items to iterate over.

Think about it - if the order of ordered collection was not preserved, any server-side sorting of results wouldn't have sense.

Comment: “ So looks like a JS and DOM issue” any solution for this issue? I kind of encounter same headache

Answer (score 0):

Iteration will depend on the type of `List` passed. So you'll have to check the docs of that type of `List`.

Comment: Are there any lists that do not preserve order? From the Javadoc: "*An **ordered** collection (also known as a sequence)*"